# Chemfig: put + between two formulas

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I want to draw a simple structural chemical formula with the chemfig package in Latex.

It schould look like the output of the code below, but i don't think that this is the right way to write it because the whole figure should be one formula with a plus in the middle and not two.

```
\setatomsep{1cm}
\chemfig{CH_4} + \chemfig{C([3]-H)([5]-H)=C([1]-H)([7]-H)}
```

[image: How it should look like:]

Comment: `\schemestart \chemfig{...} \+ \chemfig{...} \schemestop` is the way described in the manual

Comment: exactly what i wanted, i didn't know that there is a plus sign in the scheme environment

Comment: See part IV section 12 of the current `chemfig` manual :)

Answer (score 1):

```
\schemestart
  \chemfig{...}
   \+
  \chemfig{...}
\schemestop
```

is the way described in the manual:

> The use of a “`\+`” macro that displays a + sign is available between the commands `\schemestart` and `\schemestop`.